# Show content from external website iframe and prevent from framekilling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am trying to create a toolbar similar to what Stumbleupon uses. I have built a simple toolbar using an iframe but when I try to get the content of some websites, they will break out of the iframe. I have however seen another service (http://bloglovin.com) that have successfully bypassed this frame killer. What is the best method to create a toolbar like this?

Since an iframe/frameset is blockable by an external website (framekiller) is there a way to load an external website that always will work and shows they entire external website pretty much without complications. My problem is that I need a toolbar function (like stumbleupon) without and risk of the user break out of the frame.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you implement `onbeforeunload` then instead of directly closing the frameset it will prompt the user with a dialog which you can customize to let the user know they're closing the toolbar.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Why you no want toolbar!? D:';
};
```

Or if you don't want to prompt the user, you could redirect *again* to the url **with** the toolbar on that method call, but I haven't tested this so there may be something off there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However the toolbar will be an important part of the service so the user seeing the toolbar "wants" to have it, it's the external website that is the problem (framekilling).